# Time Serie with delta time travel in databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I'm storing in a delta table the prices of products. The schema of the **table** is like this:

```
id | price |  updated
1  |   3   | 2022-03-21
2  |   4   | 2022-03-20
3  |   3   | 2022-03-20
```

I upsert rows using the id field as primary key and updating the price and updated field.

I'm trying to have the serie of prices over time using databrick time travel. But looking the documentation apparently I can only look 2 versions of a table like this

```
%sql
SELECT count(distinct id) - (
SELECT count(distinct id)
FROM table TIMESTAMP AS OF date_sub(current_date(), 7))
FROM table
```

Is there a way to select the different prices off all version ? Like: Distinct prices.

Comment: Do you have to use only SQL?  I think if you can use Python, you may instead do `version = spark.sql("SELECT version FROM (DESCRIBE HISTORY my_table)").collect()` and then loop through it.  This is based on the same [doc](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/02/04/introducing-delta-time-travel-for-large-scale-data-lakes.html) you have read I think.

Comment: I was thinking in something like this mate, just want to check if there is a SQL function that allow me to select the changes of the price instead of traverse the versions and collect the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really not recommend to use time travel for that for following reasons:

- If your data is updated frequently, then you will have a lot of versions, and your performance will degrade over the time, as handling of huge number of versions (10s of thousands) will put a lot of pressure on driver
- It's very hard to do historical analysis, as you can see already - for each version you will need to have subqueries and union data.

Instead, you can use two tables - first with actual data, and second - with historical data, ideally, building the SCD Type 2 (Slowly Changing Dimensions) with markers for which period which price was active.  You can build that second table using [Change Data Feed (CDF)](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-change-data-feed.html) functionality to pull changes from first table, and applying them to the second table using MERGE operation. Databricks documentation [includes example of using MERGE to build SCD Type 2](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/merge-in-scd-type-2.html) (although without CDF).

With this approach it will be easy for you to perform historical analysis, as all data will be in the same table and you don't need to use time travel

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, two questions mate: 1) then I must keep updating my prices table, and for each update I run this process that generates the historical_prices table ? 2) would you also recommend me to decrease the days of storage for the time travel and thus avoid performance problems ?

Comment: 1) it depends how it's done - if it's batch, just create multitask job with update of historical table after ingest into "current" table is done. 2) Just use default retention periods. Performance problems may start to arise when you have > 50k versions, in the latest Delta versions maybe even more - but it all depends how often you generate new versions